# what sql query should i write to find rollno of student whose average marks are maximum where marks and student are different tables?

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate-functions

this is my student table [stud table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8gP7.png)

| rollno | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | B |
| 5 | D |
| 6 | C |

this is my marks table  [marks table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOLJU.png)

| rollno | mar | eng | maths | phy | chem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 40 | 45 | 38 | 50 | 50 |
| 2 | 28 | 50 | 45 | 41 | 38 |
| 3 | 41 | 42 | 43 | 44 | 45 |
| 4 | 45 | 44 | 43 | 42 | 41 |
| 5 | 33 | 32 | 42 | 15 | 41 |

for following query:

```
select rollno,(mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5 as average from marks;
```

I get o/p: [op](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Ku0Q.png)

| rollno | average |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 44.6000 |
| 2 | 40.4000 |
| 3 | 43.0000 |
| 4 | 43.0000 |
| 5 | 32.6000 |

now to find rollno of student whose average is maximum what query should I write?

I tried using

```
select rollno,max(
                    select (mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5 from marks
                    ) 
from marks;
```

which gives me syntax error

Answer (score 1):

The syntax on this is incorrect as the subquery returns multiple rows. Only one value should be used in the max function.

This is a better way of doing it -

```
SELECT rollno FROM marks WHERE (mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5 = (SELECT MAX((mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5) FROM marks);
```

Comment: You can drop the `/5` from each side of the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use limit 1;

```sql
    select rollno,(mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5 as average from marks
    order by (mar+eng+maths+phy+chem) desc
    limit 1
```

Comment: If more than one student has the max score, this would only display one of them.

Answer (score 0):

To get the expected data you can join your dataset with the max average :

```
select m.rollno, (mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5 as average
from marks m
inner join (
  select max((mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5) as max_average 
  from marks
) as mk on mk.max_average = (mar+eng+maths+phy+chem)/5
```